# What shall we do if the original poster asks for deletion of his own question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

### Problem background

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20419802/960757), which asks for deletion. I'm not sure if the OP is able to delete that question by him / herself (maybe he / she can't because it is in "on hold" state, or according to his low reputation).

Since the question won't keep it there for long, here is its screenshot:

[image]

### Question

What shall we do ? Shall we flag this question for moderators with a specific note (since there is no option to vote for deletion) ? Or drop a comment to the OP to tell him / her to delete the question by themselves (I'm not sure if he / she's able to do it) ?

Comment: Roll the edit back. (The user already deleted and undeleted the question, so I'm not sure what they're trying to do...)

Comment: The SO flag queue is massive.  Don't pollute it with stuff the OP could do himself, if he was more literate.  If it matters enough to the OP, he will delete it.  Post a polite comment telling him the delete link is at the bottom of the question if you feel like it.

Comment: @michaelb958, that's what I did a few hours ago to similar own question damagers ([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20390468/revisions) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20447554/revisions)), but this case explicitly asks for deletion. Well, if deletion is still allowed, I'll just drop a comment there...

Comment: Checking out the revision history, the OP actually deleted the question and then undeleted it.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP doesn't realize that questions are not hard-deleted and was confused by the fact he could still see it after deleting it.

Comment: We always see a lot of this around this time of year. Kids suddenly realize that their teachers know how to use Google, too, and desperately try to cover their tracks before the end of the term. It's cute to watch.

Comment: @BradLarson: I would *love* to see someone's teacher create an account, give them all the wrong info (ignoring the downvotes), and waiting for that student to turn in that assignment.  The teacher will refrain from revealing the truth, and the student will no longer trust SO with their copied homework.

Comment: @bradlarson Even more cute to deny it ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Michael noted in the above comment, roll back the edit first. It's a completely improper edit.

Then, you can suggest the user delete it themselves if possible (generally, an up-voted answer is what prevents deletion of a question). If you suspect they cannot delete it, generally I would leave it up to them to flag for deletion, but that's an option. Note that we don't automatically approve these deletions. We are looking at the post's true value to the site - not the OP's desire for deletion.

Also, if they roll back or reedit back to an invalid post, you should flag for mod for that.

Answer (score 8):

In response to something like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/88720/3):

[image: Mod Please Delete. Thank you for the help, it was greatly appreciated]

you should [roll the edit back](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/88720/revisions) and leave a comment like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88720/optics-law-of-cosines#comment181227_88720):

[image: Just to note, editing your question to remove the content is inappropriate on this site. We consider it vandalism. - David Z]